# Java loop for multiple projects

Tags: java

I am working in java and I want my loop to run for as long as there are projects as specified by the user. As of now, the code runs through for one iteration, and reads the results of the one loop, but it won't continue any further.

If the user says there are 3 projects, I want the code to run through the loop 3 times and tell me the total of each project. Right now, it tells me the total of 1 project whether I specify the number of projects are 1 or 5.

```
    double projectBoardFootage = 1.0;
    double projectBoardFootageTotal = 0.0;
    int i = 0;

    System.out.println("How many projects do you want to estimate?");
    int numberOfProjects = scan.nextInt();


    for(i = 0; i < numberOfProjects; ++i) {
        while (projectBoardFootage > 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter your board footage for Project #" + (i + 1) + " (0 to exit)");
            projectBoardFootage = scan.nextDouble();
            projectBoardFootageTotal += projectBoardFootage;
        }
        System.out.println("The raw board footage for Project #" + (i + 1) + " is: " + projectBoardFootageTotal);
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show what `projectBoardFootage` is when you enter the loop. Take a look at [MCVE] and [ask]

Comment: i am confused by your definition of number of projects... what do you mean by "it tells me the total of 1 project whether I specify the number of projects are 1 or 5"?

Comment: So when I run the program and am prompted by the "How many projects do you want to estimate?", I can enter any positive integer and my loop is only running once, rather than the amount of times that I've entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to reinitialize the total board footage to clear the previous iteration count?

```
for(i = 0; i < numberOfProjects; ++i) {
    projectBoardFootageTotal = 0.0;
    while (projectBoardFootage > 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter your board footage for Project #" + (i + 1) + " (0 to exit)");
        projectBoardFootage = scan.nextDouble();
        projectBoardFootageTotal += projectBoardFootage;
    }
    System.out.println("The raw board footage for Project #" + (i + 1) + " is: " + projectBoardFootageTotal);
}
```

Comment: Reinitializing the projectBoardFootage, as well as the total, is what ended up working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you're using the variable projectBoardFootage to terminate the loop.
Think about what happens when this value is set to 0.
We exit the while-loop, and the value never gets changed again. So from that point on, every iteration will end immediately.

The better solution is to do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many projects do you want to estimate?");
    int numberOfProjects = scan.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfProjects; ++i) {
        foobar(scan, i+1);
    }        
}

private static void foobar(Scanner scan, int projectNr)
{        
    boolean wantsToQuit = false;
    double projectBoardFootageTotal = 0;
    while (!wantsToQuit) {
        System.out.println("Enter your board footage for Project #" + projectNr + " (q to exit)");
        String tmp = scan.next();
        if(tmp.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
           wantsToQuit = true;
        else
            projectBoardFootageTotal += Double.parseDouble(tmp);
    }
    System.out.println("The raw board footage for Project #" + projectNr + " is: " + projectBoardFootageTotal);        
}
```

This code also ensures the user enters a more sensible keycode than '0' to quit.